# TreeView: checkboxes only in child nodes

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a treeview control:

1. Root nodes don't have checkboxes, only images.
2. All child nodes have a checkbox + image.

C#, .net 2.0, winforms (not wpf)

Answer (score 2):

The WinForms tree view does not support mixed checkbox/non checkboxes nodes by default

You can enable CheckBoxes globally on the tree view and disable them on specific nodes using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698369/how-to-disable-a-winforms-treeview-node-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable checkbox.
First Set TreeView **DrawMode** property as **OwnerDrawAll**.
Then Under DrawNode method check child node collection and set **checked** property as **false**
ie.

```
private void xmlStructureTree_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Node.Nodes.Count != 0)
            {
                e.Node.Checked = false;
            }
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
```

Comment: this unchecks it, not hide or disables.