# TreeView turn off checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have very strange problem with hiding CheckBoxes in a TreeView. Everything works as it should when TreeView is on the first TabPage in the Window but when TreeView in on the second TabPage then the first TreeNode always has checkbox.

[image: root node without checkbox]  [image]

The code I'm using to hide some checkboxes looks like this:

```
private const int TVIF_STATE = 0x8;
private const int TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK = 0xF000;
private const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
private const int TVM_SETITEM = TV_FIRST + 63;

public struct TVITEM {
    public int mask;
    public IntPtr hItem;
    public int state;
    public int stateMask;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public int iSelectedImage;
    public int cChildren;
    public IntPtr lParam;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


private void TurnOff(TreeNode node) {

    TVITEM tvi = new TVITEM();
    tvi.hItem = node.Handle;
    tvi.mask = TVIF_STATE;
    tvi.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
    tvi.state = 0;
    IntPtr lparam = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvi));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvi, lparam, false);
    SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_SETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, lparam);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lparam);
}
```

If someone knows solution for this problem, please share.

Comment: Just guessing: Would it help to first select the 2nd Page?

Comment: Try to modify the treeview properties: set CheckBoxes to false.

Comment: disabling all checkboxes isn't a solution because I want them in child nodes. They should only be invisible in parent nodes

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819108/treeview-checkboxes-only-in-child-nodes)

Comment: This is a rather regrettable hack that has appeared in several SO questions.  The nasty memory leak in TurnOff() certainly is problematic, calling Marshal.FreeHGlobal() is not optional.  The hard-coded "wezel" is probably what you are complaining about, make that "node".

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you for your remark

Comment: ALSO: if you use this method of hiding be ready to see your hidden checkboxes again when you press a space key. It will check focused checkboxes and return their visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution can be found here: http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2011/05/winforms-treeview-hide-checkbox-of-treenode/