# how to disable particular check boxes in C# Winform Treeview control with check box option?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TreeView Remove CheckBox by some Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes)

In my C# Windows Form Application, I have Treeview control with checkboxes.

I want to prevent the user from checking particular nodes' checkboxes. How can stop the user from being able to check particular ones?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698369/how-to-disable-a-winforms-treeview-node-checkbox

Comment: @V4Vendetta, that's for removing, not disabling.

Answer (score 1):

[TreeView.AfterCheck Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) is one option to prevent checking nodes. I find this is an easy way of doing it. But there can be better ways.

```
private void node_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
   // The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
   if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
   {
      if(e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
      {
         //Check whether that is a valid checkbox
         // If not you can uncheck it.
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit**

To hide the checkboxes. Look at Cody Gray's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes/4826740#4826740).

Comment: We dont allow the user to check the check box.While creating that particullar tree node, i want to create the specific tree node with check box disabled.

Comment: Why don't you hide checkboxes rather than disabling as you have asked in other question. Again this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes

Comment: My thought is exactly what u said...Is this possible?

Comment: @ Saravanan : Look at here. This should work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826556/treeview-remove-checkbox-by-some-nodes/4826740#4826740

Comment: @ Sarvanan : I've updated my answer with the link to Cody Gray's answer.