# treeView with checkBoxes for selected nodes

Tags: c#, checkbox, treeview, treenode

I'm working with application, which use TreeView. I want some nodes have 
checkBoxes, but not all.
I know that I can do:

```
    treeView.CheckBoxes = true;
```

But then all nodes have checkBox. How can I add checkBox only for selected
nodes?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698369/how-to-disable-a-winforms-treeview-node-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx) class it seems you'll have to implement a custom `OnDrawNode` function and perform some `Tag` manipulation.

An example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9fbc737b-8385-4285-aa80-0e4602ff5b9b/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a new template for your treeviewitem, or your dataitems.

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="checkBox" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="checkBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

edit: Obviously, this is for WPF.
If you are using WinForms, then this will not be of any help. Sorry.