# joining 3 tables using inner join in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am working with `winforms` in .NET 3.5 and `sql server 2005` using c#.

i need to join 3 tables such as `Advance_cost`,`room_no_info` and `bill` using inner join...

```
SELECT
      bill.bill_no AS BillNo
    , COUNT(room_no_info.room_number) AS TotalRoom
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.in_date, 106) AS InDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.out_date, 106) AS OutDate
    , bill.total AS Amount
    , Advance_cost.total_amount AS Advance
    , Advance_cost.total_amount AS Paid
    , bill.Balance AS Balance
FROM room_no_info
INNER JOIN bill ON bill.bill_no = room_no_info.bill_no
INNER JOIN Advance_cost ON bill.bill_no = Advance_cost.room_bill_no 
     AND bill.Date = '26-Jun-13'
GROUP BY
      bill.bill_no
    , room_no_info.in_date
    , room_no_info.out_date
    , bill.total
    , Advance_cost.total_amount
    , bill.Balance
```

in `advance_cost` table data may be empty or no data for the date of `bill.date`. so third condition in join gets false so it doesn't shows some data but i need `Advance_cost.total_amount=0` when third table values gets empty

is there any idea?

Comment: What is the connection between the question title and the question content?

Comment: @king King , see it http://stackoverflow.com/q/17290489/1427849 , did he copied the title ? :)

Comment: @zey yes, I was the answerer to that question and felt surprised when looking at the title of this question and more surprised when the asker is exactly him :)

Comment: sorry sorry... i missed to see the title of Question... and updated

Comment: @Bala you should also update your query with uppercase keywords such as select -> SELECT, ... and break the lines at appropriate point, for example, FROM should start a new line, GROUP BY should do the same, ... That would help others feel easy to see your query and can give out some solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN and ISNULL

```
SELECT
      bill.bill_no AS BillNo
    , COUNT(room_no_info.room_number) AS TotalRoom
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.in_date, 106) AS InDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.out_date, 106) AS OutDate
    , bill.total AS Amount
    , ISNULL(Advance_cost.total_amount, 0) AS Advance
    , ISNULL(Advance_cost.total_amount, 0) AS Paid
    , bill.Balance AS Balance
FROM room_no_info
INNER JOIN bill ON bill.bill_no = room_no_info.bill_no
LEFT JOIN Advance_cost ON bill.bill_no = Advance_cost.room_bill_no 
     AND bill.Date = '26-Jun-13'
GROUP BY
      bill.bill_no
    , room_no_info.in_date
    , room_no_info.out_date
    , bill.total
    , Advance_cost.total_amount
    , bill.Balance
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      bill.bill_no AS BillNo
    , COUNT(room_no_info.room_number) AS TotalRoom
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.in_date, 106) AS InDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), room_no_info.out_date, 106) AS OutDate
    , bill.total AS Amount
    , ISNULL(Advance_cost.total_amount, 0) AS Advance
    , ISNULL(Advance_cost.total_amount, 0) AS Paid
    , bill.Balance AS Balance
FROM room_no_info
INNER JOIN bill ON bill.bill_no = room_no_info.bill_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN Advance_cost ON bill.bill_no = Advance_cost.room_bill_no 
     AND bill.Date = '26-Jun-13'
GROUP BY
      bill.bill_no
    , room_no_info.in_date
    , room_no_info.out_date
    , bill.total
    , Advance_cost.total_amount
    , bill.Balance
```